# Unordered map in shared_ptr SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, lambda, threadpool, shared-ptr, c++14

I'm building server for speech recognizer. I'm using thread pooling to serve clients.

I needed to create unordered map to save instance of recognizer for each client. So I create this_

```
std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<int ,SOnlineSpeechRecognizerI *>> user_recognizers;
std::mutex rec_mutex;
```

So on client connection I create instance of recognizer and I need to insert data to user_recognizers. My lambda function for that is :

```
echo.onopen=[user_recognizers, &rec_mutex](auto connection) {
    std::cout << "Server: Opened connection " << (size_t)connection.get() << std::endl;
    SOnlineSpeechRecognizerI *rec = recognizer::initRecognizer();
    if(!rec){
        connection.
    }
    std::pair<int, SOnlineSpeechRecognizerI *> myrec ((size_t)connection.get(), rec);
    rec_mutex.lock();
    (*user_recognizers).insert(myrec); //error here
    rec_mutex.unlock();
};
```

connection.get() return int ID of the connection.

I'm getting SIGSEGV. Valgrind gives me a little hint:

```
Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
```

Comment: Do you initialize `user_recognizers` with anything e.g by calling `make_shared()`?

Comment: how can I do it ? I thought make_shared is different type of shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you don't initialize `user_recognizers`, therefore it holds a null pointer leading to segfault when you access it.

You can initialize it for example like this:

```
using MyMap = std::unordered_map<int ,SOnlineSpeechRecognizerI *>;
std::shared_ptr<MyMap> user_recognizers { std::make_shared<MyMap>() };
```

(I assume `user_recognizers` is a some class member so it can't be declared with `auto`)